WIFIMAN Desktop not working in Ubuntu 24.04
I downloaded Wifiman desktop a deb file and installed it in my computer which was successful but upon clicking it, it doesn't load up like nothing happens.

What are you trying to do? I did not know what that app was so I did a Google search and when I clicked on it on the web site the speed test started. Please make it clear what it is you are trying to do and what steps you have followed as well as any errors or messages you get. Please do not answer in a comment, edit the question and add the info.

Your post looks incomplete.
As David mentioned above, please edit your post by adding the relevant inputs, so that we can help you accordingly.

You're right. It doesn't work. Here's a discussion thread https://community.ui.com/questions/WifiMan-Desktop-Ubuntu-24-04/a371a232-1c79-45f3-ba63-6ea8d101a6dc

I was having the exact same issue. The workaround that ended up working for me is I had installed an old wifiman deb, version 0.3.0 as well as run it with
cd "/opt/Wifiman Desktop"
./wifiman-desktop --no-sandbox &
it works flawlessly now.  Understand this may be a security risk. But you can get to it via internet archive:
http://web.archive.org/web/20240322114117/https://ui.com/download/app/wifiman-desktop
The ampersand at the end makes it run in the background and allows you to close the terminal.
I even tried the steps outlined in the comments here https://community.ui.com/questions/WifiMan-Desktop-Ubuntu-24-04/a371a232-1c79-45f3-ba63-6ea8d101a6dc but they did not work for me.

This is just a workaround. Open a terminal and go to /opt/WiFiman.
Execute the following command and it should open:
./wifiman-desktop --no-sandbox

